Spread Duration of a Fixed Rate Corporate Bond, with offsetting Futures Position
My question is relatively simple with respect to the below scenario:

I take a $5m long position in a vanilla fixed-rate corporate bond with a spread of 1.50% for a YTM of 5%. These coupons are paid semi-annually. I therefore have total mod duration of 7.7945y, and therefore 3,897.29 DV01.

The 10y benchmark yield is therefore 3.50% and the 10y futures contract, has a DV01 per contract, of $93.93.


As I solely want to have exposure to the credit spread and hedge all duration risk, I short approximately 42 contracts (3,897.29 / 93.93). I am therefore long a 5% yield, and short a 3.5% yield, giving me a net yield or spread of 1.50%.
My question is, how do I now calculate the spread duration of the total position, such that I can measure how sensitive my corporate bond is to changes in credit spread?
I am confused at this point here because I have no obligation to pay the coupons on the short 3.50% position, instead I continue to receive the 5% coupon on the corporate fixed rate and have an offsetting position should benchmark rates rise.
So therefore, my original duration figure for the bond is essentially 0, but I also know that for a fixed rate bond, the spread duration is equivalent to modified duration.
For further context, my implied notional contract value for futures is $120,941.10.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

In my opinion, durations, including modified, key rate, et al, ...)  are less transparent ways of quantifying risk than dv01. I suggest you measure instead the sensitivities, by tenor bucket, to the risk-free rates and to the spread. See, for example,  https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/78147/allocating-bond-pnl-in-a-similar-way-to-swaps/78151#78151 -
